# Ember.js using link to query params subexpressions

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm using query-params in the link-to helper for sorting. It works well. However, I need to enable a reverse sort option when someone hits the link. For example, first time sorts from A-Z then second time hitting the link it would sort from Z-A. Any idea how to implement this? I have tried the query-params subexpression helper but can't seem to get the options to switch back and forth. Basically I need to use title and -title since that is how the server expects them for sorting. I have a Django backend.

Controller:

```
App.PostsIndexController = EmberArrayController.extend({
queryParams: ['sortBy'],
sortBy: 'title',
direction: null,
});
```

I've also tried:

```
sortBy: 'title:-title"
```

Route:

```
App.PostsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
queryParams: {
 sortBy: {
  refreshModel: true
}
},

model: function (params)
  return this.store.find('post', {
   sort: params.sortBy
  })
}
```

});

I've also tried adding this after the line sort: params.sortBy

```
direction: params.direction
```

Template: (excerpt)

```
{{#link-to 'posts' (query-params sortBy="title" direction=-title:title)}}A-Z
    <span class="caret"></span>
{{/link-to}}
```

I've also tried:

```
{{#link-to 'posts' (query-params sortBy="title" direction="-title:title")}}A-Z
    <span class="caret"></span>
{{/link-to}}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I feel like there must be something I'm missing and haven't been able to find it in Google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you point out, your backend is forcing you to combine `sortBy` and `direction` into a single property by accepting either `title` or `-title`.

What you need is the ability to dynamically change the value of your `sortBy` property, when the user clicks the sort link.  I would add an `{{action 'clickSort'}}` to the link you want to trigger the sorting, and then define that action in your controller.

Since you've set `refreshModel: true`, any change to the `sortBy` property will automatically make another REST call to your backend.

Here's an example:

```
App.PostsIndexController = EmberArrayController.extend({
    queryParams: ['sortBy'],
    sortBy: 'title',

    actions: {
        clickSort: function() {}
            if ( this.get('sortBy') === 'title' )
                this.set('sortBy', '-title');
            else
                this.set('sortBy', 'title');
        }   
});
```